# Windows Phone application rating is not displaying

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

Our company has published an application  in windows Store on 21st april 2015.

And many user have downloaded the application and many have rate it. But it is not displaying in the application page yet.

And I also checked with logging in Windows developer account. Still I could not see it.

Please provide clarification. From a developer side, do we need to do anything  for displaying rating information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a developer, you don't need to do anything. It is handled by Store itself.
However, I have sometimes experienced little delay in the ratings appearing in Store listing. I guess that's probably the case here. Wait and check after some time.